# More than 6 cameras in Nvidia Jetson boards

Tags: quadcopter, localization

A recent startup named Skydio develops autonomous drones for photography. The drone is named as R1 and utilizes 13 cameras to map its surroundings for localization and motion planning. The brain of this drone is Nvidia Jetson TX1. While the number of cameras that a TX1 board can support is 6. I'm wondering how did they manage to use 13 cameras. 
Can anyone know the answer to this question?

Comment: `Can anyone know the answer to this question?` the person that designed R1

Answer (score 1):

From the [Nvidia Jetson datasheet](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/jetson-tx2-delivers-twice-intelligence-edge/) , it seems that 12 cameras are supported. The bandwith per camera is just smaller when you have more cameras as there is a limitation in the number of lanes and you get more cameras per lane.

I suspect that the 13th camera is the one actually filming the subjects but it's a bit unclear from Skydio  website, which is legitimate for a high-tech product.